# Starting Scala Play App with Scaldi using Java

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt, scaldi

I built a Scala Play app with Scaldi for DI. I used sbt:assembly to generate a fat jar which I'm hoping to be able to start up by simply using

```
java -jar /path/to/jar
```

with some additional configs. It seems however when I do this I get a bunch of missing bindings and then have to add BuiltinModules.scala as an enabled module in application.conf. Within BuiltinModules.scala there are dynamic bindings that are pulling in from my configs. I then find myself having to add a bunch of unneccessary configs into my application.conf. For example:

```
play.http.filters = "my.custom.Filters"
play.http.requestHandler = "play.http.DefaultHttpRequestHandler"
play.http.actionCreator = "play.http.DefaultActionCreator"
play.http.context = "/"
```

This seems like a very poor way of doing this. Has anyone gone through this before?

I'm using play 2.5.10 with Scaldi 0.5.15 and scala version 2.11.8.